# Using .Equals on a constant to avoid (save) null check

Tags: c#, equals

So here is standard code for IValueConverter

```
{
 if (value == null)
  return null;

 if (value.Equals(true))
  return Colors.Red;

 return null;
}
```

And another way:

```
{
 if (true.Equals(value))
  return Colors.Red;

 return null;
}
```

So, by using true.Equals() we are saving a null check. What are general approach and best practices in regards to using true.Equals() or "Hello".Equals() type checks?

P. S. My question is: what is your/general opinion on this: bad/hacky or ok/nice?

Comment: Do you think that null check is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: No, that is not the point AND it will be checked anyways inside .Equals(). My idea is make code smaller and easier.

Comment: The cases where you can do is very minimal (Just strings come to mind). If you can have something like `true.Equals(value)`, chances are you dealing with a value type and don't have to worry about null check. Besides null check is not that big of a deal.

Comment: `{ return true.Equals(value) ? Colors.Red : null; }` This is when doing such things as removing things that you have no reason to remove since they're already there get overboard.

Comment: Ok, then I will just assume that your goals are really in conflict to writing good maintainable code.  You're not making your code "Easier" (whatever that means), you're making its intent more obscure.

Comment: I agree Ed S, code should be easy to maintain and its intent should be obvious. true.Equals(value) isn't obvious intent in my book, nor is ternary operator with magic constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Equals method generally checks for null anyway, but if you're trying to optimize your code by removing a single null check, you're really missing the mark.  This is not going to make a difference in virtually any application.

Comment: `The .Equals method generally checks for null anyway` but there will be a null reference exception if the object on with the Equals is called itself is null.

Comment: value.Equals will throw NullException if value is null. And idea is not too tune performance, but make code smaller

Comment: My point was that there's still null checks going on.  Why do you need to make the code smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong preference for shorter code (and by that I mean less tokens, not using undecipherable short identifiers) - it is often more readable and understandable, less bug prone, and gives you less code to maintain.

So leaving the null check to .Equals by using true.Equals is a clear win in my book.

In this particular example, you could even remove the duplicate return and do

```
return true.Equals(value) ? Colors.RedColors.Red : null;
```

but some might find that less readable than the if statement.

Comment: this is a clear loss in my box because readability is gone in the window, when you return here after a couple of months youll have no idea what is going on and what is the desired behaviour of function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be probably using base generic class for converters, which has a `virtual` strongly typed method, in which case you aren't dealing with `object`, but instead with a `bool` inside your converter code.

If we are stuck with object value I am advocate of readable and maintanable code and short functions which replace ifs which can become obscure in future.

So id be using smth like

```
{
 if(IsValueBoolAndTrue(value){
    return ErrorColor;
 }
 else {
    return DefaultColor;
 }
}
```

`Color.Red` and `null` are constants which make their intent unclear too. Also having those 2 constants defined can help with converting back in second method of IValueConverter

Although method `IsValueBoolAndTrue` technically does same thing as `true.Equals(value)` does (inside itself it can call this actually), having a special method will help person, who looks at this in future, not to make a "refactoring" which will break code, because he would look at `true.Equals(value)` with no comments and think that its actually not smth that is suitable or will think that its inelegant code and refactor it, without leaving its funcionality the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `NullReferenceException` and "funny" calls like `true.Equals(value)` by using the static [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Because the method is implement by `Object` it is available in all methods and it will perform the necessary null checks for you:

```
return Equals(value, true) ? (Object) Color.Red : null;
```

or if you dislike the ternary operator:

```
if (Equals(value, true))
  return Color.Red;
return null;
```